# PayPal-PHP-SDK code errors

Tags: php, paypal

I am using Paypal-PHP. SDK, a I want to get code errors. When I put wrong credit card data, I am getting this JSON as answer:

```
{
"name":"CREDIT_CARD_REFUSED",
"message":"Credit card was refused",
    "information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api    /#CREDIT_CARD_REFUSED",
"debug_id":"63a9cf220d272"
}
```

or this:

```
{"name":"VALIDATION_ERROR",
       "details":[
            {"field":"payer.funding_instruments[0].credit_card.expire_month","issue":"Must not be blank"},
            {"field":"payer.funding_instruments[0].credit_card.expire_year","issue":"Must not be blank"},
            {"field":"payer.funding_instruments[0].credit_card.cvv2","issue":"Must be numeric"}],
       "message":"Invalid request - see details","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#VALIDATION_ERROR","debug_id":"8e61a15a1bf4a"}
```

But I need error code. How Can I get it?

Thanks

Comment: I would recommend sticking with the classic API for a while personally.  This [PayPal PHP SDK](https://www.angelleye.com/product/paypal-sdk-php/) makes those calls very quick and easy for you, and it's still has more features than REST has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

REST API usually do not return error codes like classic API. There are no error codes associated with the error message.

It just returns the error object with `name` `debug_id` `message` `information_link` `details`